# how can I show image description on a page

Tags: wordpress, image

Wordpress 6.3
I have a image description in my media, I would show this in my normal side content.
Not in Posts.

For Posts I wrote this in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'custom_description', 10 );
function custom_description( $html ) {
      $beschriftung = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
      if ($beschriftung != '') { 
        $html .= '<p class="em_bild">' . $beschriftung . '</p>';
      }
    return $html;
}
```

but this don't work on normal pages.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how is this not working on normal pages?

Comment: I have subsequently changed the description in the media library and would now like it to be displayed automatically under all images.
It only works if I insert the image into the text again.